# I changed my username and it would not let me go on servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I changed my username and I tried logging back on and when I got back on, Minecraft would keep saying

> Error: Authentication To Minecraft.Net Failed

All the servers I visited also said this.

Comment: Please don't use excessive emoticons in future. Thanks!

Comment: I thought you had to sign in with your email, rather than username?

Comment: Trying logging out and logging back in.